# $(\int(\int f(x,y) dy)^p dx)^{\frac{1}{p}} \leq \int(\int f(x,y)^p dx)^{\frac{1}{p}} dy $

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If $f: \mathbb{R}^2: \to \mathbb{R}$  measurable Lebesgue positive then for 
$ 1 ≤ p ≤ ∞$

$(\int(\int f(x,y) dy)^p dx)^{\frac{1}{p}} \leq \int(\int f(x,y)^p dx)^{\frac{1}{p}} dy $ .

A suggestion to solve this problem, thank you very much for your attention